# Zxing reader does not initialize unless page refreshed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following block is generated by the zxing library on first page paint

```
<div id="sourceSelectPanel" style="display:none">
  <label for="sourceSelect">cambia sorgente video :</label>
  <select id="sourceSelect" style="max-width:400px">
  </select>
</div>
```

when the page is re-loaded, the CSS styling changes to `style="display:block"` and the console will indicate `ZXing code reader initialized` as per 5th line of following script.

The script is invoked on the page directly (*indents are to distinguish personalisations from stock code*)

Thus, the script does not appear to load on first page call, but does with a page refresh.

Note this is a rails 7.0.4 application. pinning via `bin/importmap pin @zxing/library` has been unsuccessful as the reader never initializes.

How can these scripts load properly on this given page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@zxing/library@latest/umd/index.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      let selectedDeviceId;
      const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
      console.log('ZXing code reader initialized')
      codeReader.listVideoInputDevices()
        .then((videoInputDevices) => {
          const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
          selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
          if (videoInputDevices.length >= 1) {
            videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
              const sourceOption = document.createElement('option')
              sourceOption.text = element.label
              sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
              sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
            })

            sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
              selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
            };

            const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById('sourceSelectPanel')
            sourceSelectPanel.style.display = 'block'
          }

          document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video', (result, err) => {
              if (result) {
                console.log(result)
                document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text
let formData = new FormData();
let CodeParams = {
  code_data: result.text,
  section_id: <%= session[:selected_section] %>
};
formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams));
/* Rails.ajax({
  url: "barcode_section_update",
  type: "post",
  data: formData
  }); */
fetch("barcode_section_update", {
  method: "post",
  format: "turbo_stream",
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content,
  }
});
codeReader.reset();
              }
              if (err && !(err instanceof ZXing.NotFoundException)) {
                console.error(err)
                document.getElementById('result').textContent = err
              }
            })
            console.log(`Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`)
          })

          document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            codeReader.reset()
            document.getElementById('result').textContent = '';
            console.log('Reset.')
          })

        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err)
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using Turbo or Turbolinks?  If so then change the addEventListener to listen for 'turbo:load' or 'turbolinks:load' respectively.